# Directory truncation and converted to string issue in macOS Bash shell script

Tags: bash, macos, shell

```
thisPath="/Users/admin/Sites/codebase/projects/DrawingProject"
modifiedPath="$($thisPath|rev|cut -d '/' -f-2|rev)"

printf "[[[[[  $modifiedPath ]]]]]\n"
```

In macOS BASH How can I get the following to print:

```
[[[[[  projects/DrawingProject ]]]]]
```

Right now I get a directory error

Thank you. -Jonathan

Comment: All good stuff below, and prefered, but I'll comment if you changed to `mPath=$(echo "$thisPat" | rev | ....` that solution might work also. You need the `echo` to "send" the data into the pipe for proper munging ;-) Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do is with `awk`:

```
thisPath="/Users/admin/Sites/codebase/projects/DrawingProject"
modifiedPath=$(awk -F/ '{print $(NF-1)"/"$NF}' <<< $thisPath)

printf "[[[[[  $modifiedPath ]]]]]\n"
```

Output:

```
[[[[[  projects/DrawingProject ]]]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `bash` supports [Parameter Expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion)

```
$ thisPath="/Users/admin/Sites/codebase/projects/DrawingProject"
$ echo "[[[[[  ${thisPath#${thisPath%/*/*}/} ]]]]]"
[[[[[  projects/DrawingProject ]]]]]
```

To understand this, consider the different parts of it:

```
$ echo "${thisPath%/*/*}"
/Users/admin/Sites/codebase
```

- `%` is used to remove minimal match from end of string
- `/*/*` so this would remove `/projects/DrawingProject` containing `/` followed by any characters followed by `/` and again followed by any characters

Similarly, `#` allows to remove minimal match from start of string. For ex:

```
$ echo "${thisPath#/*/}"
admin/Sites/codebase/projects/DrawingProject
```

Combining both concepts:

```
$ echo "${thisPath#${thisPath%/*/*}/}"
projects/DrawingProject
```

- `${thisPath%/*/*}` will give `/Users/admin/Sites/codebase`
- and then the extra `/` is given
- So, in effect, `/Users/admin/Sites/codebase/` will be removed and we get `projects/DrawingProject`

Answer (score 0):

That is a good answer. Here is another way of doing it using `basename` and `dirname`

```
thisPath="/Users/admin/Sites/codebase/projects/DrawingProject"    
printf "[[[[[  $(basename $(dirname $thisPath))/$(basename $thisPath)  ]]]]]"
```